# How to mark Entity Framework class properties as 'Obsolete'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some fields in Entity Framework entities which I would like to mark as [Obsolete]. Is it possible?

I have the following auto-created code:

```
namespace Data.Databases
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Address
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried adding metadata like this:

```
namespace Data.Databases 
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(AddressMetadata))]
    public partial class Address 
    {
    }
    public class AddressMetadata 
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work. It compiles ok, but it doesn't show the field as obsolete in VS.

Is it something I am doing wrong or is it just not possible?

*(I am using EF6 with C#4.5 in VS2012.)*

Comment: `Obsolete` is a compiler feature that knows nothing about `MetadataType`.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks. So that's not the route to go then.

Comment: It is not really an answer to my question, but to resolve the issue I changed to using Code First and I am really liking it - far more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an interface that has the member marked as `Obsolete`.

```
namespace Data.Databases 
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(AddressMetadata))]
    public partial class Address : IAddress
    {
    }
    public class AddressMetadata 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IAddress
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Making the Address class inherit from IAddress doesn't make VS highlight the field as 'Obsolete' either.